# Windows Azure (dotnetnuke module installation error)

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

1. I'm new with windows Azure and i've just signup for a 3months free trial, i've installed dotnetnuke 7.0.1 the problem that i have is that everytime when i try to install a module on to my dotnetnuke website i get the sql error message, please help as i don't know what is the problem.
2. my windows Azure is disabled because i've created more than 1 databases but now i've deleted all the other databases now i'm left with one, how do i reactivate my trial so i can complete my tests.

Comment: *I get the sql error message* - can you share the error please.

Comment: Can you share with us which module did not work when you installed it?

Answer (score 5):

1. The problem with the modules that you are trying to install is probably that are not SQL Azure compatible. Ensure that those modules are compatible with SQL Azure asking to the module developer/vendor. If the problem is within the open source/non-core modules, some time ago I modified all of them to be SQL Azure compatible (check this link: http://dotnetnuke6.intelequia.com/Module-Test). Before install any of them, be sure that there is no new version at CodePlex with the SQL Azure compatibility fixed.
2. I think the problem is that the SQL Azure "billing" counter is calculated "per day". So you should wait at least one day before creating a new database or just disable the trial limits by converting the subscription to a paid subscription

Comment: In addition to the above, you can upload any DotNetNuke extension to the DNN Extension Verification Service (EVS). This will (among other things) test the module for SQL Azure compatibility before you install it on your system. EVS is designed for free use by extension developers (vendors, corporate, and personal) and consumers to verify their packages. It's easy to use: evs.dotnetnuke.com

Answer (score -1):

---I WORK FOR [POWERDNN](http://www.PowerDNN.com)---

Hi Anonymous,

While Azure does have some advantages, when it comes to running an app like DotNetNuke on Azure, it is really not a good business or technology decision (at least today).  Right now Azure does not have parity with standard SQL Server technologies which is what DotNetNuke has been coded against for the past ten years.

I've already talked to more than a couple associates who have tried to run their DNN website on Azure and it has caused serious problems for them,  Usually what happens is a SQL script won't completely run and will leave their database in an indeterminate state.  The problems usually aren't apparent to them until a few weeks after trying out azure and then they have to decide to either roll back (and loose weeks of data) or spend hours trying to figure out what script didn't fully run and trying to piece things back together in an azure-compatible way.

If you have never had to rewrite a vendor's SQL scripts, I'd highly encourage the experience.  It is a lot of "fun" :-)

Always glad to help,

Tony V.